# Why does the TOP function does not work in SQLite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

When I tried to SELECT a certain number of rows from my database, I was unsure how to do this, and so searched it up on google. The TOP function was the first result, but when I tried it in SQLite3 it did not work, and some other people recommended LIMIT. Does anyone know why TOP did not work?

Comment: Neither `TOP` nor `LIMIT` are SQL Standard.  That honor goes to `FETCH`.  Database vendors can implement whatever they want; the standard is a good place to start, but adherence to the standard is often observed more in the breach than in the adherence.

Comment: SQLite syntax for select is described at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html btw.

Comment: Thank you Shawn!